# Firebase Functions Deploy: Error while parsing function triggers

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am having an issue deploying firebase functions from an angular project.  I have updated to latest firebase-tools 7.8.1. In my project package.json i have "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0", "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0" and "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6".

Any suggestions welcomed

Firebase.json

```
{
"firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
},
"functions": {
    "predeploy": []
},
"hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"]
}
```

}

The error below does not seem to be pointing to any of my files

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

...\functions\node_modules\xtend\immutable.js:1



SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\users\craig\Google Drive\craig\career\fowi\samples\fuse_v8.12_skeleton\functions\node_modules\through2\through2.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
```

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the node_modules folder under the functions directory and did a fresh npm i.  That did the trick

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that you a running firebase deploy from the correct dir.
- Make sure that you have latest Firebase-funtions

  npm i --save firebase-functions@latest
- Delete node_modules and do a fresh npm i